# how can i find the initial letters of all the words in a .txt file

Tags: c

I'm a bit green in C and whole programming so I need help on task.

i am trying to find the answer of this question and all i came up with is this code that works but
output:

```
vhiag
hwag
tiatg
```

required output:

```
vhiag
hw
tiat
```

```
size=sizeof(ss)/sizeof(ss[0]);
        if(strcmp(op,"first")==0){

            while(1){
            if(fgets(ss,512,fp)==NULL){
                break;
                }
                first(ss,size);
            } 

        } 
void first(char spaces[],int size)
{
        int i=1;
        char r[size];
        r[0]=spaces[0];
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {

            if(spaces[j]==' ')
            {
                r[i]=spaces[j+1];
                        i++;
            }
        }
        r[i]='\0';
       printf("%s\n",&r); 
        return; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Oh, and don't forget to tell us the *input* to you give the program as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `first()` function scans the whole array presented to it, all `size` bytes, without regard to the presence of a string terminator within.  Therefore, if an input line is shorter than the previous one, your function blithely scans the overlay of the second line on the first.

To stop your scan at the end of the line, break from the loop when you see the terminator:

```
    for (j = 0; spaces[j] != '\0'; j++)
```

You may also break on the condition that `j` reaches or exceeds `size` (as an *additional*, not alternative condition), but it's not really necessary in your case because you can rely on `fgets()` to provide that terminator within the number of bytes specified to it.